# Why does RVM Ruby require libksba?

Tags: ruby, rvm

The `rvm requirements` says I should install "libksba" before installing Ruby 1.9.3.

1. Why?
2. How can I tell if I already have "libksba" installed?

I'm running Mountain Lion 10.8.2 and Xcode 4.5 (4G182).

Comment: Wouldn't this be better asked of the RVM support folks?

Comment: @theTinMan actually I do not know exactly - it has something to do with security/openssl ... but no details from my side (I am RVM Release Manager)